# Почему при парсинге страницы не срабатывает decimal=',' и запятые не заменяются точками?

Tags: python, html, парсер, dataframe

Цель, скачать таблицу для анализа.
Запускаю парсинг:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.cbr.ru/hd_base/itogidepauct/Full/?UniDbQuery.Posted=True&UniDbQuery.From=07.07.2020&UniDbQuery.To=01.09.2020&UniDbQuery.Atype=0'
data = pd.read_html(url, index_col=0, decimal=",")
data[0]
```

Таблица скачивается, но запятые не заменяются точками, а исчезают. Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: А почему они должны заменяться?

Comment: потому что у вас по умолчанию в методе `pd.read_html` атрибут `thousands` тоже равен ",". поэтому добавьте перед `decimal=","` параметр `thousands=None` или, лучше, `thousands=" "`.

Comment: @dIm0n потому что добавлен параметр  decimal=",". "Знак, который нужно распознать как десятичную точку (например, используйте ',' для европейских данных)." https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там тысячи разделены пробелом. Если добавить `thousands=" "`, то все нормально парсится.

```
data = pd.read_html(url, index_col=0, decimal=",", thousands=" ")
```

Проверка типов:

```
data[0].dtypes
```

```
Тип инструмента                                                  object
Срок депозита                                                    object
Дата привлечения денежных средств в депозит                      object
Дата возврата депозита и уплаты процентов                        object
Максимальный объем привлекаемых денежных средств (млрд руб.)      int64
Объем в заявках (млрд руб.)                                     float64
Количество кредитных организаций, подавших заявки                 int64
Максимальная возможная ставка в заявке (% годовых)              float64
Минимальная заявленная ставка (% годовых)                       float64
Максимальная заявленная ставка (% годовых)                      float64
Способ проведения аукциона                                       object
Ставка отсечения (% годовых)                                    float64
Средневзвешенная ставка (% годовых)                             float64
Объем привлеченных денежных средств (млрд руб.)                 float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Надо же, мне просто нужны были только ставки, поэтому решил с тысячами ничего не делать, а оказалось это влияло на float!!!! Спасибо!